# Ubuntu 20.04 : error when installing Caffe

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, cmake, opencv, caffe

I'm trying to install Caffe-Segnet (http://mi.eng.cam.ac.uk/projects/segnet/tutorial.html) on my Ubuntu 20.04 for a project I'm working on, and I encountered many difficulties, even when trying to mimic the many tutorials I found on the installation of standard Caffe, due to the fact that many libraries it uses are outdated.

This was when I found and followed this tutorial, which I thought would solve all my problems :
https://qengineering.eu/install-caffe-on-ubuntu-20.04-with-opencv-4.4.html

However, I encounter an error during the "Building Make" step. After having followed all of their instructions, I execute :

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
        -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
        -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \
        -D BUILD_TIFF=ON \
        -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON \
        -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON \
        -D WITH_TBB=ON \
        -D BUILD_TBB=ON \
        -D WITH_EIGEN=ON \
        -D WITH_V4L=ON \
        -D WITH_LIBV4L=ON \
        -D WITH_VTK=OFF \
        -D WITH_QT=OFF \
        -D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
        -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
        -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
        -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF \
        -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON \
        -D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON \
        -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
        -D OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON \
        -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=ON \
        -D CUDA_FAST_MATH=ON \
        -D CUDA_ARCH_BIN=7.5 \
        -D WITH_CUBLAS=ON \
        -D WITH_CUDNN=ON \
        -D CUDNN_LIBRARY=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so.8.0.5 \
        -D CUDNN_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/cuda/include  \ 
        -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF ..
```

Since I have an NVIDIA GeForce RTX2060 and cuDNN 8.0.5 installed, I changed the corresponding lines in this command :

```
-D CUDA_ARCH_BIN=7.5 \
-D CUDNN_LIBRARY=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so.8.0.5 \
```

However, the execution of this command returns this error message :

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detected processor: x86_64
CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:721 (message):
  Unexpected option: WITH_CUBLAS (=ON)

  Condition: IF (WITH_CUDA)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:249 (OCV_OPTION)


CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:721 (message):
  Unexpected option: WITH_CUDNN (=ON)

  Condition: IF (WITH_CUDA)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:252 (OCV_OPTION)


-- Found PythonInterp: /home/anass/anaconda3/bin/python (found suitable version "3.8.3", minimum required is "2.7") 
CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVDetectPython.cmake:81 (message):
  CMake's 'find_host_package(PythonInterp 2.7)' found wrong Python version:

  PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/anass/anaconda3/bin/python

  PYTHON_VERSION_STRING=3.8.3

  Consider providing the 'PYTHON2_EXECUTABLE' variable via CMake command line
  or environment variables

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/OpenCVDetectPython.cmake:271 (find_python)
  CMakeLists.txt:599 (include)


-- Could NOT find Python2 (missing: Python2_EXECUTABLE Interpreter) 
-- Found PythonInterp: /home/anass/anaconda3/bin/python3 (found suitable version "3.8.3", minimum required is "3.2") 
-- Could NOT find PythonLibs: Found unsuitable version "3.8.5", but required is exact version "3.8.3" (found /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so)
-- Looking for ccache - not found
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FFAST_MATH
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FFAST_MATH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FFAST_MATH
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FFAST_MATH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_W
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_W - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_W
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_W - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WALL
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WALL - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WALL
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WALL - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_ADDRESS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_ADDRESS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_ADDRESS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_ADDRESS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WFORMAT
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WFORMAT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WFORMAT
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WFORMAT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WINIT_SELF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WINIT_SELF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WINIT_SELF
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WINIT_SELF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WPOINTER_ARITH
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WPOINTER_ARITH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WPOINTER_ARITH
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WPOINTER_ARITH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSIGN_PROMO
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSIGN_PROMO - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNINITIALIZED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNINITIALIZED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSUGGEST_OVERRIDE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSUGGEST_OVERRIDE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSUGGEST_OVERRIDE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSUGGEST_OVERRIDE - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_COMMENT
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_COMMENT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_COMMENT
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_COMMENT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_sse.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE2 (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_sse2.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE3 (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_sse3.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSSE3 (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_ssse3.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSSE3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE4_1 (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_sse41.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE4_1 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MPOPCNT (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_popcnt.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MPOPCNT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE4_2 (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_sse42.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE4_2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MF16C (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_fp16.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MF16C - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MFMA
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MFMA - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MAVX (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_avx.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MAVX - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MAVX2 (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_avx2.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MAVX2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MAVX512F (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_avx512.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MAVX512F - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MAVX512F_MAVX512CD (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_avx512common.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MAVX512F_MAVX512CD - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MAVX512F_MAVX512CD_MAVX512VL_MAVX512BW_MAVX512DQ (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_avx512skx.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MAVX512F_MAVX512CD_MAVX512VL_MAVX512BW_MAVX512DQ - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_BASELINE_FLAGS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_BASELINE_FLAGS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_SSE4_1
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_SSE4_1 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_SSE4_2
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_SSE4_2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_FP16
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_FP16 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_AVX
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_AVX - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_AVX2
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_AVX2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_AVX512_SKX
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_AVX512_SKX - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_LINK_AS_NEEDED
-- Performing Test HAVE_LINK_AS_NEEDED - Success
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for posix_memalign
-- Looking for posix_memalign - found
-- Looking for malloc.h
-- Looking for malloc.h - found
-- Looking for memalign
-- Looking for memalign - found
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found suitable version "1.2.11", minimum required is "1.2.3") 
-- Found JPEG: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (found version "80") 
-- Looking for assert.h
-- Looking for assert.h - found
-- Looking for dlfcn.h
-- Looking for dlfcn.h - found
-- Looking for fcntl.h
-- Looking for fcntl.h - found
-- Looking for inttypes.h
-- Looking for inttypes.h - found
-- Looking for io.h
-- Looking for io.h - not found
-- Looking for limits.h
-- Looking for limits.h - found
-- Looking for memory.h
-- Looking for memory.h - found
-- Looking for search.h
-- Looking for search.h - found
-- Looking for string.h
-- Looking for string.h - found
-- Looking for strings.h
-- Looking for strings.h - found
-- Looking for sys/time.h
-- Looking for sys/time.h - found
-- Looking for unistd.h
-- Looking for unistd.h - found
-- Performing Test C_HAS_inline
-- Performing Test C_HAS_inline - Success
-- Check size of signed short
-- Check size of signed short - done
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Check size of signed int
-- Check size of signed int - done
-- Check size of unsigned int
-- Check size of unsigned int - done
-- Check size of signed long
-- Check size of signed long - done
-- Check size of unsigned long
-- Check size of unsigned long - done
-- Check size of signed long long
-- Check size of signed long long - done
-- Check size of unsigned long long
-- Check size of unsigned long long - done
-- Check size of unsigned char *
-- Check size of unsigned char * - done
-- Check size of size_t
-- Check size of size_t - done
-- Check size of ptrdiff_t
-- Check size of ptrdiff_t - done
-- Check size of INT8
-- Check size of INT8 - failed
-- Check size of INT16
-- Check size of INT16 - failed
-- Check size of INT32
-- Check size of INT32 - failed
-- Looking for floor
-- Looking for floor - found
-- Looking for pow
-- Looking for pow - found
-- Looking for sqrt
-- Looking for sqrt - found
-- Looking for isascii
-- Looking for isascii - found
-- Looking for memset
-- Looking for memset - found
-- Looking for mmap
-- Looking for mmap - found
-- Looking for getopt
-- Looking for getopt - found
-- Looking for memmove
-- Looking for memmove - found
-- Looking for setmode
-- Looking for setmode - not found
-- Looking for strcasecmp
-- Looking for strcasecmp - found
-- Looking for strchr
-- Looking for strchr - found
-- Looking for strrchr
-- Looking for strrchr - found
-- Looking for strstr
-- Looking for strstr - found
-- Looking for strtol
-- Looking for strtol - found
-- Looking for strtol
-- Looking for strtol - found
-- Looking for strtoull
-- Looking for strtoull - found
-- Looking for lfind
-- Looking for lfind - found
-- Performing Test HAVE_SNPRINTF
-- Performing Test HAVE_SNPRINTF - Success
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_VARIABLE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_VARIABLE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_STD_C99
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_STD_C99 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_VARIABLE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_VARIABLE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_FUNCTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_FUNCTION - Success
-- Could NOT find OpenJPEG (minimal suitable version: 2.0, recommended version >= 2.3.1)
-- Could NOT find Jasper (missing: JASPER_LIBRARIES JASPER_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_IMPLICIT_FUNCTION_DECLARATION
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_IMPLICIT_FUNCTION_DECLARATION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNINITIALIZED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_PARAMETER
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_PARAMETER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_POINTER_COMPARE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_POINTER_COMPARE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_ABSOLUTE_VALUE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_ABSOLUTE_VALUE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_STRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_STRICT_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.11") 
-- Found PNG: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (found version "1.6.37") 
-- Looking for /usr/include/libpng/png.h
-- Looking for /usr/include/libpng/png.h - found
-- Found OpenEXR: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so
-- Checking for module 'gtk+-3.0'
--   Found gtk+-3.0, version 3.24.20
-- Checking for module 'gthread-2.0'
--   Found gthread-2.0, version 2.64.3
-- TBB: Download: v2020.2.tar.gz
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_CLASS_MEMACCESS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_CLASS_MEMACCESS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_IMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_IMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH - Success
-- IPPICV: Download: ippicv_2020_lnx_intel64_20191018_general.tgz
-- found Intel IPP (ICV version): 2020.0.0 [2020.0.0 Gold]
-- at: /home/anass/packages/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv
-- found Intel IPP Integration Wrappers sources: 2020.0.0
-- at: /home/anass/packages/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/iw
-- Could not find OpenBLAS include. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
-- Could not find OpenBLAS lib. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
-- Could NOT find Atlas (missing: Atlas_CLAPACK_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Looking for sgemm_
-- Looking for sgemm_ - not found
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Looking for sgemm_
-- Looking for sgemm_ - found
-- Found BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblas.so  
-- Looking for cheev_
-- Looking for cheev_ - found
-- A library with LAPACK API found.
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_LOCAL_TYPEDEFS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_LOCAL_TYPEDEFS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_PROMO
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_PROMO - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_TAUTOLOGICAL_UNDEFINED_COMPARE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_TAUTOLOGICAL_UNDEFINED_COMPARE - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_IGNORED_QUALIFIERS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_IGNORED_QUALIFIERS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_EXTRA
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_EXTRA - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_FUNCTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_FUNCTION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_CONST_VARIABLE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_CONST_VARIABLE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHORTEN_64_TO_32
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHORTEN_64_TO_32 - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_INVALID_OFFSETOF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_INVALID_OFFSETOF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ENUM_COMPARE_SWITCH
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ENUM_COMPARE_SWITCH - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SUGGEST_OVERRIDE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SUGGEST_OVERRIDE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_INCONSISTENT_MISSING_OVERRIDE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_INCONSISTENT_MISSING_OVERRIDE - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ARRAY_BOUNDS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ARRAY_BOUNDS - Success
-- Could NOT find JNI (missing: JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
-- Looking for dlerror in dl
-- Looking for dlerror in dl - found
CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:288 (message):
  No modules has been found: /home/anass/opencv_contrib/modules
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:370 (_glob_locations)
  modules/CMakeLists.txt:7 (ocv_glob_modules)


-- ADE: Download: v0.1.1f.zip
-- OpenCV Python: during development append to PYTHONPATH: /home/anass/packages/opencv/build/python_loader
-- Checking for modules 'libavcodec;libavformat;libavutil;libswscale'
--   Found libavcodec, version 58.54.100
--   Found libavformat, version 58.29.100
--   Found libavutil, version 56.31.100
--   Found libswscale, version 5.5.100
-- Checking for module 'libavresample'
--   Found libavresample, version 4.0.0
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-1.0'
--   Found gstreamer-base-1.0, version 1.16.2
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0'
--   Found gstreamer-app-1.0, version 1.16.2
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-1.0'
--   Found gstreamer-riff-1.0, version 1.16.2
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0'
--   Found gstreamer-pbutils-1.0, version 1.16.2
-- Checking for module 'libdc1394-2'
--   Found libdc1394-2, version 2.2.5
-- Allocator metrics storage type: 'long long'
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED_DECLARATIONS - Success
CMake Error at modules/dnn/CMakeLists.txt:35 (message):
  DNN: CUDA backend requires CUDA Toolkit.  Please resolve dependency or
  disable OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=OFF


-- Registering hook 'INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn': /home/anass/packages/opencv/modules/dnn/cmake/hooks/INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn.cmake
-- opencv_dnn: filter out cuda4dnn source code
-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV 4.4.0 =====================================
--   Version control:               unknown
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Timestamp:                   2020-11-15T10:48:27Z
--     Host:                        Linux 5.4.0-53-generic x86_64
--     CMake:                       3.16.3
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               RELEASE
-- 
--   CPU/HW features:
--     Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
--       requested:                 SSE3
--     Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
--       requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
--       SSE4_1 (15 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
--       SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
--       FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
--       AVX (4 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
--       AVX2 (29 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
--       AVX512_SKX (4 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ standard:                11
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 9.3.0)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a   -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed  
--     Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a   -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed  
--     ccache:                      NO
--     Precompiled headers:         NO
--     Extra dependencies:          dl m pthread rt
--     3rdparty dependencies:
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc ml objdetect photo stitching ts video videoio
--     Disabled:                    world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 java js python2 python3
--     Applications:                perf_tests apps
--     Documentation:               NO
--     Non-free algorithms:         YES
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     GTK+:                        YES (ver 3.24.20)
--       GThread :                  YES (ver 2.64.3)
--       GtkGlExt:                  NO
--     OpenGL support:              NO
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.11)
--     JPEG:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver 80)
--     WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.6.37)
--     TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.10)
--     JPEG 2000:                   build Jasper (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so (ver 2_3)
--     HDR:                         YES
--     SUNRASTER:                   YES
--     PXM:                         YES
--     PFM:                         YES
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394:                      YES (2.2.5)
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       avcodec:                   YES (58.54.100)
--       avformat:                  YES (58.29.100)
--       avutil:                    YES (56.31.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (5.5.100)
--       avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
--     GStreamer:                   YES (1.16.2)
--     v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)
-- 
--   Parallel framework:            TBB (ver 2020.2 interface 11102)
-- 
--   Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
--            at:                   /home/anass/packages/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv
--     Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
--               at:                /home/anass/packages/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/iw
--     Lapack:                      NO
--     Eigen:                       YES (ver 3.3.7)
--     Custom HAL:                  NO
--     Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)
-- 
--   cuDNN:                         NO
-- 
--   OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
--     Include path:                /home/anass/packages/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Link libraries:              Dynamic load
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /home/anass/anaconda3/bin/python3
-- 
--   Java:                          
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         NO
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Install to:                    /usr/local
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/anass/packages/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/anass/packages/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I had to remove some lines I deemed uninteresting because I went over the 30k characters limit.
If needed, I can provide the content of the `CMakeOutput.log` and `CMakeError.log` files as they are too massive to be included in this question.

How can I solve my problem ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

These few lines from your error message shows the problem:

```
-- Found PythonInterp: /home/anass/anaconda3/bin/python (found suitable version "3.8.3", minimum required is "2.7") 
CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVDetectPython.cmake:81 (message):
  CMake's 'find_host_package(PythonInterp 2.7)' found wrong Python version:

  PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/anass/anaconda3/bin/python

  PYTHON_VERSION_STRING=3.8.3

  Consider providing the 'PYTHON2_EXECUTABLE' variable via CMake command line
  or environment variables
```

It needs python 2.7 and can't find it, so it's asking you to provide the path to python 2.7, so first locate python 2.7 on your device and if it's not installed, install it with `sudo apt install python2.7` and then pass the location of python 2.7 to the CMake this way:

```
cmake -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/yourpath/to/python2.7 \
        your-other-stuff \
        ... \
        ...
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your help ! I followed your instruction, but it now tells me it cannot find my PythonLibs and to set the PYTHON_LIBRARIES and PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS flags. The problem is that I cannot find a libpython2.7.so file anywhere in my system, but I can find libpython3.8.so. I thought maybe, since the error message indicates that cmake found Python3.8.3 but libpython3.8.so was of the 3.8.5 version, I could try to correct this incompatibility. How could I resolve one of these problems ?